# Nintendo Digital Zelda Breath of the Wild Wii U transfer to Switch

Tags: wii-u, zelda-breath-of-the-wild, nintendo-switch

Does the wii u digital version of Zelda Breath of the Wild count the same as Switch Zelda Breath of the Wild version?

IE if you own wii u Zelda breath of the wild, Will it count as owning Zelda breath of the wild on Switch? Or will it not count and have to buy twice?

I don't have a switch to test this on so. Otherwise I would test it myself.

Comment: They are separate.

Comment: You might want to reconsider buying a switch if that's what you were implying. They're suffering from countless problems

Comment: What problems? This question is about transferring product between wii u and switch. I am mostly asking because I already brought wii u ahead of time for Zelda breath of the wild. It helps to know if I need to dish out $60 in additional to switch console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the Wii U and Switch games are separate products.

At this time the Switch has no connectivity with other Nintendo hardware. The only linkage on the console is that the friends list has awareness to the lists in their mobile apps.

Comment: "The only linkage on the console is that the friends list has awareness to the lists in their mobile apps." Oh, is that why they went back to friends codes instead of just using your Nintendo Network ID like the WiiU did?

Comment: The Switch and mobile games use a "Nintendo Account," which is different from the "Nintendo Network ID." You can link the two together, though it makes no attempt to look at Wii U or 3DS friends lists.

Comment: Good point about the Wii U having no account link (technically) to the Switch. (But my NNID is linked to by Nintendo Account.)


But also, the Wii U version is optimized to run on Wii U hardware, with Wii U inputs. The Switch version is optimized to run on Switch hardware, with Switch input devices. So they are separate versions of the game.

It would be very beneficent of Nintendo to choose to a make the Switch version free, after they link it all to one account. They didn't do that for Virtual Console titles between the Wii and Wii U.

Comment: A discount was offered for Virtual Console games upgraded from Wii to Wii U, but that was only available after a convoluted process of transferring the older console's purchases to the newer one, thanks to complete backwards compatibility. Only recently did Nintendo update the terms for the Nintendo Account, not NNID, to tie purchases to the online account, rather than unique hardware. This means a possible future of digital purchases moving forward, but the Wii U and 3DS will not follow.